How to migrate Subdomains to new hosting?
I have migrated my website from a local hosting company to hostinger. I have done following.

Full Backup up my website from cpanel.
Used hostinger internal migration wizard
migration completed.

I had one subdomain of this website hosted on local hosting server. I have below queries.

Will it be migrated automatically?
How can I host same subdomain with all posts on hostinger just like before I was hosting on local hosting.


Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
